# How can I build an OData $filter string from an Expression in C#?

Tags: c#, odata

I have been reading the docs at http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#04-02-query-options for the client .net library to consume OData services.

The docs make it clear how to consume a service, but sometimes we just need to retrieve the $filter part of the url.

So, like the question title asks, is there any way to obtain the $filter string corresponding to a given Expression?

What I'm looking for might look like this:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate = p => p.Name == "test";
string filter = GetFilter(predicate); // "Name eq 'test'"
```

Is this possible without having to write an ExpressionVisitor from scratch?

Comment: If it's at all possible (I know nothing about this) , it wouldn't be with a `Func<T, TResult>` but rather with an `Expression<Func<T,TResult>>`. Note: It's almost definitely possible by parsing the expression tree... I just don't know if a library exists to do such a thing though.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question correcting that

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this, did you find some solutions?

Comment: @MateuszRadny not really, sorry. At the time I ended up doing this manually for the number of cases that the application needed, and, soon after, the product was sold to a different software vendor so I no longer keep track of it.